# What is the reason of error Status: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries, Code: 1?

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I've installed Docker on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 64 bit as on the first screenshort. During the process I've got an error, but docker -v shows installed version.

Then I tried to run my docker-compose file and got an error (look at the second screenshort).

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

**Important notice**: the project successfuly runs on Windows 10.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to have attached a couple of images to the question in place of the actual log output from `docker-compose` and the source code necessary to reproduce the issue.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] and the relevant log output, as text and not images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the error is stating that there is no such image built for windows architecture.

If you go on [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags&page=1&name=16.13.1-alpine3.13) for this exact image, you can see under OS/ARCH there are only linux/amd , linux/* images built, that means you cant use this as your base image on your Windows architecture.

So you really have two options.

- you find an image that is built for windows/amd64 [like this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/stefanscherer/node-windows/tags)
- you simply create your own windows/amd64 image and use that for your base image

Comment: Comment: That the project successfully runs on windows 10, probably has something to do with you using Docker Desktop, which actually emulates minimal Linux VM to run Docker in it hence base image there works, since it runs in Linux, not windows environment. Here you are actually using Windows Containers (if you would want to mimic the actual environment on development machine i suggest you turn on Windows Containers inside Docker Desktop settings).

Comment: @microsoft is always so difficult.. ugh.. thank you for this